# Javascript Not Working On Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to hide Division B on [this page](http://aslsportsny.com/basketball/standings/?team=36). Due to the nature of the Wordpress template, it's kind of difficult to do. I am trying to use javascript in the footer:

```
$('div#division-2 div.teampage').prev('h2').css("display","none");
```

This works [perfectly on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxQ3J/2/), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I also created a javascript file with the code. Can someone please give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header, you have this code:

```
var $jquery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

This disables the `$` shortcut. Replace `$` with `jQuery` or `$jquery` in your code. For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div#division-2 div.teampage').prev('h2').css("display", "none");
});
```

The reason the code in `hide-division.js` isn't working is that while it *is* using `$jquery` (for `$jquery(document).ready`, at least; it still needs to use that in the body of the handler), `hide-division.js` is running before the code calling `noConflict`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `hide-division.js` file, code is like:

```
$jquery(document).ready(function()
{
$('div#division-2 div.teampage').prev('h2').css("display","none")
});
```

Here `$jquery is not defined` so the next code is not executing. Please remove jquery and use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('div#division-2 div.teampage').prev('h2').css("display","none")
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Icktoofay's solution worked below.

Answer (score 0):

just try giving $('div#division-2 h2').css("display","none");

$jquery must not given... its invalid... either $ or jQuery must be given...

This [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) may help u...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!